# create an audio object for an array of sound elements jquery, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, audio

I have currently a number of sound elements like this

```
var AudioGood = document.createElement('audio');
AudioGood.controls = true;
AudioGood.src = 'sounds/good.wav';
AudioGood.volume=0.5;

var AudioWrong = document.createElement('audio');
AudioWrong.controls = true;
AudioWrong.src = 'sounds/wrong.wav';
AudioWrong.volume=0.5;
```

and so on. I don;t like that. I try to make something like

```
function track (name,controls,src,volume,loop){
    this.name = name;
    this.controls = controls;
    this.src = src;
    this.volume = volume;
    this.loop = loop;
}

var music = [
new track ('AudioGood',true,'sounds/good.wav',0.5,false),
new track ('AudioWrong',true,'sounds/wrong.wav',0.5,false),
new track ('musicBackground',true,'sounds/background.ogg',0.5,true),
new track ('AudioDrop',true,'sounds/drop.wav',0.5,false),
new track ('AudioCard',true,'sounds/card.wav',0.5,false)
];
```

But I need to create a audio element, document.createElement('audio'). how would I do that? it's probably a stupid question, but please be merciful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `track` as a constructor, you can just return an audio element from your `track` function.

```
     function track (name,controls,src,volume,loop) {

            var  audio = document.createElement('audio');

          audio.name = name;
          audio.controls = controls;
          audio.src = src;
          audio.volume = volume;
          audio.loop = loop;

         return audio;

    };

var music = [
   track('AudioGood',true,'sounds/good.wav',0.5,false),
   track('AudioWrong',true,'sounds/wrong.wav',0.5,false),
   track('musicBackground',true,'sounds/background.ogg',0.5,true),
   track('AudioDrop',true,'sounds/drop.wav',0.5,false),
   track('AudioCard',true,'sounds/card.wav',0.5,false)
];
```

Comment: Thanks Jayson, I have tried the code. But nothing happens. sounds are not playing now. How should I call that in the code? currently it is called by AudioGood.play(); I have tried by music[index].play() - not working. obviously I do it wrong.

Comment: Sorry my bad, it's working perfectly fine if called by music[index].play(); Just a sintax error... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The most logical way is to create a property like `element` pointing to DOM element:

```
function Track (name, controls, src, volume, loop) {
    this.name = name;
    this.element = document.createElement('audio');
    this.element.controls = controls;
    this.element.src = src;
    this.element.volume = volume;
    this.element.loop = loop;
}
```

Also even though properties of `this.element` are publicly accessible, it would be good design choice to create necessary getter/setter methods on track prototype. For example:

```
Track.prototype.setVolume = function(value) {
    this.element.volume = value;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I should have specify: I don't need to bind the sounds with a specific elements. that's noting to do with players. (I actually do not need volume, ar controls I think.) I'm making a kind of game where I use some sounds (that some is getting bigger). I call the sounds on drop, or change of the screen.

Comment: All right, sound to me that it will work for this too.

Comment: I have made the cahnges to the track function like you've said, but it won't work. Now the sound is called by name.play() (like AudioGood.play() ) but music[index]. also won't work.

Comment: Can you post your code in jsfiddle so I can check how you implemented new function?